# Change direction of installation in Mac OS

Tags: mactex

I am new to Mac OS and I used to work with MikTex on Windows.

As a habit inherited from Windows, I'd like to install MacTex distribution on the other partition of the hard drive other than the one where system has been installed.

Is there a possibility to achieve this target?

Comment: Untested: install MacTeX normally, copy `/usr/local/texlive` to the other partition and then replace the original directory with a symbolic link to the one in the partition.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry for the dumb question, but how can I access /usr/..., do you mean using terminal? The later part is where I am totally lost. Where can I set up the symbolic link?

Comment: I really don't recommend doing this unless you are *comfortable* at the command line. Note that following this suggestion will not exclude installed files from your system partition because MacTeX also installs things in other places e.g. `/Library/PreferencePanes` and something like `/usr/texbin` although I forget the details etc. Note that `/usr/local` is *intended* for non-system software. That's where well-behaved third-party stuff installs itself.

Comment: It would be better to ask: what corresponds on a Mac to installing on a separate partition on Windows? And the answer will not be: installing on a separate partition. Ask: why do I have this habit? Probably because it is best practice on Windows. So, ask: what is best practice in OS X? Doing things according to habits formed on Windows is dangerous. You will worry about risks which don't exist while failing to take precautions against the dangers you should worry about.

Comment: Perhaps I should add: I am not saying separate partitions are a bad thing. I do have TeX Live on a separate partition. But I'm using Linux. I would not recommend doing it on OS X, at least without a good basic understanding of Darwin. Personally, I would be a lot more bothered about the fact that MacTeX installs TeX Live with root ownership of `/usr/local/texlive` which is not recommended by upstream. I wouldn't be especially worried by this. But I would be more worried about this than about installing to the same partition as the OS.

Comment: @cfr Generally wise advice, especially the part about not doing this unless one is comfortable with the system and the command line,  although the very last part of your last comment is a bit off base, IMO. BTW, `/usr/texbin` is itself symbolic link, and the stuff installed in `/Library` is part of the system support for MacTeX rather than TeX Live per se, so it should remain in any system partition anyway.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your thorough comments. I am quite comfortable with terminals. At least I also have a Tex Live distribution on my working station with Linux system. The main interest of installing softwares on a separate partition is because it would be easier to monitor the usage of storage and to clean up after uninstallation.

Comment: @AlanMunn Perhaps I should make clear that I would not be worried about installing MacTeX if I had a Mac. Just that if I *was* going to worry about it, I would worry about ownership rather than about the partition. The ownership means `tlmgr` has to run with root privileges. I do think it is better to avoid that. I think the advantages of MacTeX outweigh that slight risk and I trust the people responsible for it. But I wouldn't worry about putting it on the same partition at all. I know `/usr/texbin` is a link. So is much of what is in `/Library` (though not all). Everything is a file, though.

Comment: @cfr If I may ask, do you suggest when partition is not a wise choice on Mac OS X, in the contrast of other systems?

Comment: In that case, I would make a separate partition and mount that at `/usr/local` or `/usr/local/texlive` just as you would on Linux.

Comment: It is just that Apple have set things up so that OS X really likes being on a single partition. For example, it is a lot more hassle to maintain a separate `/Users` partition than a separate `/home` partition. I think it is different with `/usr/local` because the system doesn't really care about that so you won't get unexpected complications. (Note that the most recent version of OS X I've used is 10.4 so take what I say under advisement.) In the end, I think you have to pick your battles and make sure it is really worth it. By the way, it is pretty easy to delete `/usr/local/texlive` anyway.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the quick response. I think I will give up this thought and just go with the way of using mac in the dummy way.